# Fahrenheit to Celsius Conversion in C++. But why it doesn't work?

Tags: c++

### ***Fahrenheit to Celsius or Celsius to Fahrenheit Conversion***

### ***But it doesn't work and I need help***

1. ***f = Fahrenheit***
2. ***c = Celsius***
3. ***resultC = Result that appears while Fahrenheit converts to Celsius***
4. ***resultF = Result that appears while Celsius converts to Fahrenheit***
5. ***a = switch between (Celsius(C)/Fahrenheit(F))***

---

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;

        char a;
        float c,f;
        float resultC, resultF;

        resultF = c*9.0/5.0+32.0;
        resultC = (f-32.0)*5.0/9.0;    


        int main () {

         cout << "Enter your operation (C/F):" << endl;
         cin >> a;

         switch (a) {

          case 'C':
              cout << "Enter your number to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit:" 
           <<endl;
                  cin >> c;

              cout << resultF << endl;

              break;

          case 'F':
              cout << "Enter your number to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius"                         
           <<endl;

              cin >> f;

              cout << resultC << endl;

              break;
          }

       }
```

**When I run the program results are wrong**

**PS, I'm new at C++ please don't judge so hard**

***Thank you for any help!***

Comment: You have to do the calculations ***after*** taking the input.

Comment: Also important: You cannot have expressions outside of a function except in initialization. `resultF = c*9.0/5.0+32.0;` Bad and triggers compiler error. `float resultF = c*9.0/5.0+32.0;` Good. Combine this information with @user0042 's comment and you should be good to go.

Comment: You can't use a variable's value until after you assign it a value.

Comment: Rewirte your expressions (`resultF` and `resultC`) as a function definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to understand that the use of global variables should be avoided

```
char a;
float c,f;
float resultC, resultF;
```

The reason you are getting wrong answers is because you are calculating `resultF` and `resultC` before actually taking user input which provides you with garbage values. You need to take **input from the user first then calculate your results**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    char a;
    float c,f;
    float resultC, resultF;

cout << "Enter your operation (C/F):" << endl;
 cin >> a;

 switch (a) {

  case 'C':
      cout << "Enter your number to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit"<<endl;
          cin >> c;
      resultF = c*9.0/5.0+32.0;
      cout << resultF << endl;
      break;

  case 'F':
      cout << "Enter your number to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius"<<endl;

      cin >> f;
      resultC = (f-32.0)*5.0/9.0;  
      cout << resultC << endl;
      break;
  }
```

}

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing calculations for doing conversion before you have read the input.
You should read the input and then do the conversions as necessary.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char a;
float c,f;
float resultC, resultF;

int main () {

    cout << "Enter your operation (C/F):" << endl;
    cin >> a;

    switch (a) {

        case 'C':
            cout << "Enter your number to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit:" << endl;
            cin >> c;
            resultF = c*9.0/5.0+32.0;
            cout << resultF << endl;
            break;

        case 'F':
            cout << "Enter your number to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius"<<endl;                         
            cin >> f;
            resultC = (f-32.0)*5.0/9.0;
            cout << resultC << endl;
            break;
    }

}
```

You can see in the above code that calculation is done after the input is read.

In your code you are using global variables to store the result and input. Which is not necessary here as there are no other functions you have to share those values.

You can add those variables inside the `main()` and make it local. You can make them local and re-write the code like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main () {

    char a;
    float c,f;
    float resultC, resultF;

    cout << "Enter your operation (C/F):" << endl;
    cin >> a;

    switch (a) {

        case 'C':
            cout << "Enter your number to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit:" << endl;
            cin >> c;
            resultF = c*9.0/5.0+32.0;
            cout << resultF << endl;
            break;

        case 'F':
            cout << "Enter your number to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius"<<endl;                         
            cin >> f;
            resultC = (f-32.0)*5.0/9.0;
            cout << resultC << endl;
            break;
    }

}
```

So, If you are declaring a variable outside a function it is global. That is it's value can be accessed and altered by other functions in the program.
If a variable is declared inside the scope of the function it is local to that function. That means, that variable can be used only inside that function.

You can follow this [link](https://www.codesdope.com/cpp-scope-of-variables/) to learn more and understand about the scopes.

Hope this helps.!

Comment: Why global variables?

Comment: I have mentioned it in the edit.!!

Comment: I have shown both approaches now so that he can see what are the differences.

Comment: Yes. My bad. I meant local. I have edited.